# SQL Server 2012 not visible on local network

Tags: sql-server

Currently I have SQL Server running on a local machine and it is working. However I would like to connect to it with my other machines on the network. The other machines do not see this SQL Server. Do I need to configure the sever to allow remote connections? If so how can I do ths and where. Thank you.

Comment: Is this the express edition, or one of the "full" flavours?

Comment: This is express edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be listening by default I believe, but I suspect the Windows firewall is not permitting the connections. Go to Control Panel, Windows Firewall, along the left side is a task/wizard for letting an application through in a specific zone that will build the more complex rules for you.

If however SQL server is NOT already listening, then someone with more experience will have to help you.

Answer (score 1):

1.Check your sql server browser is running or not if it is stopped start sql browser.
2.May be your windows firewall is blocking,if you are using default port 1433 allow the port.